# how to deploy tensorflow system? tensorflow serving?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

I have built a recommender system with tf.keras.

I'd like to deploy this to a live environment.

One thing I could do is, create a python-based webserver (django) that takes (http) rest request, do the `prediction` with the trained model and gives back the result as a rest response.

I wonder if there's recommended alternative than doing the above?

I can guess [tensorflow serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) might be related to what I'm trying to do, but couldn't tell for sure..

- I'm subsclassing tf.keras.models.Model to create my model, and it doesn't support `model.save()` only `model.save_weights` .. It might affect my options I guess.

Comment: Can you define the issue you're having more precisely. Why do you need an alternative? What's not working with your current approach? What's wrong with the tf.keras model? (you don't need to use django models or the django ORM to serve a view)

Comment: Tesnsorflow serving is the way to go here.

Comment: Ok.. so tensorflow serving does this.. how do I close this ? or @Karioki could answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesnsorflow serving is the way to go here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving

It has some very good features: https://youtu.be/CxUc5FJF_9w?t=1056
And this video is very informative in general about TensorFlow serving and TFX.